# Use Postgres generated columns in Sequelize model

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table where it's beneficial to generate a pre-calculated value in the database engine rather than in my application code.  For this, I'm using [Postgres' generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) feature.  The SQL is like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "Items"
ADD "generatedValue" DOUBLE PRECISION GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  LEAST("someCol", "someOtherCol")
) STORED;
```

This works well, but I'm using Sequelize with this database.  I want to find a way to define this column in my model definition, so that Sequelize will query it, not attempt to update a row's value for that column, and ideally will create the column on sync.

```
class Item extends Sequelize.Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init({
      someCol: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
      someOtherColl: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
      generatedValue: // <<<--  What goes here??
    });
  }
}
```

How can I do this with Sequelize?

I can specify the column as a DOUBLE, and Sequelize will read it, but the column won't be created correctly on sync.  Perhaps there's some post-sync hook I can use?  I was considering `afterSync` to drop the column and re-add it with my generated value statement, but I would first need to detect that the column wasn't already converted or I would lose my data.  (I run sync [without `force: true`] on every app startup.)

Any thoughts, or alternative ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't the most possible right now:  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12718

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Until Sequelize supports readOnly fields and the GENERATED datatype, you can get around Sequelize with a custom datatype:

```js
const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
  someCol: { type: DataTypes.DOUBLE },
  someOtherCol: { type: DataTypes.DOUBLE },
  generatedValue: {
    type: 'DOUBLE PRECISION GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LEAST("someCol", "someOtherCol")) STORED',
    set() {
      throw new Error('generatedValue is read-only')
    },
  },
})
```

This will generate the column correctly in postgres when using `sync()`, and prevent setting the `generatedValue` in javascript by throwing an Error.

Assuming that sequelize never tries to update the field if it hasn't changed, as specified in https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html#change-awareness-of-save, then it should work.

Comment: This works great, thank you!  One follow-up question... is using a string for a type officially documented somewhere?

Comment: I could not find any mention in the docs, so it could be behaviour that is subject to change in future versions of sequelize.

Comment: This unfortunately does not seem to work anymore as of Sequelize v6.32.1