# Running a row query while defining Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have defined a Sequelize model but I want to have a column that use other columns query results.
like:

```js
const test = sequelize.define('test', {
  geom: {
    type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326),
    //value: sequelize.query(`SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${coordx}, ${coordy}),4326)`)

  },
  coordx: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    allowNull: false
  },
  coordy: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  timestamps: false
})
```

So as you see, I want to use **coordx** and **coordy** and convert to Geometry and add it value to **geom** column

Comment: Does the geom column exist in the database, or is it a sequelize [virtual column](https://sequelizedocs.fullstackacademy.com/virtual-columns/)?  If it's possible to just have a PostgreSQL [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) and then map that to a `DataTypes.GEOMETRY` property in sequelize, then you wouldn't have to recalculate it unless coordx or coordy changed in the database, right?

Comment: Lets say the column is there in DB but it has no value. In each row it gets its value from coordx and coordy calculated.

Comment: I did some more digging, and it looks like there might be a better way to go instead of sequelize virtual columns.  I tried to explain in an answer below.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12718) in Github right now to support read-only columns in `sequelize`.  However, mentioned at the bottom of the issue is a [workaround posted by mtkopone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051281/use-postgres-generated-columns-in-sequelize-model/67120448#67120448).  As per his suggestion, the PostgreSQL table could have a column definition for `geom` as

```
create table if not exists test (
    id          bigserial not null,
    geom        geometry(point,4326) generated always as (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(coordx, coordy),4326)) stored,
    coordx      decimal not null,
    coordy      decimal not null,
    constraint  pk_testgeos primary key (id)
);
```

Then the `sequelize` model could be defined by

```
let Test = sequelize.define('test', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        geom: {
            type: 'geometry(point,4326) generated always as (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(coordx, coordy),4326)) stored',
            set() {
                throw new Error('geom is read-only')
            }
        },
        coordx: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
            allowNull: false
        },
        coordy: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'test'
    })

let test = await Test.create({
        coordx: 3.14,
        coordy: 3.14
    })  // Some random place off the coast of Africa where hopefully they serve pie....
```

Using the above pattern, any new inserts or updates into the `test` table will result in the `geom` column being updated automatically.  See [PostgreSQL's documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) where they talk about generated columns.

The coordinates for the `geom` property can be accessed as follows (see the [sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js%7EGEOMETRY.html) for more info):

```
console.log(`Geometry type: ${test.geom.type}`)
console.log(`Geometry coordinates: ${test.geom.coordinates}`)
```